# A Boolean quotient ring of a prime ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-rings

I am searching for a unital prime ring $R$ such that its right socle $Soc(R_R)$ is nonzero and proper, and such that $R/Soc(R_R)$ is a Boolean ring (i.e., all its elements are idempotent).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let $F$ be the two-element field, let $V$ be a countably infinite dimensional $F$-vector space. Let $E$ be the ring of endomorphisms of $V$, and set $R$ to be the subring of $E$ generated by its socle and $1$. Then $R$ is prime (easy: what are the ideals of $R$?), the socle of $E$ equals the socle of $R$, and the quotient is just $F$, in particular, a Boolean ring.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Thanks a lot for your contribution! I thought about the prime-ness  of $R$, but I just didn't get any thing. Would you please explain to me about the ideals of $R$?

Comment: Here is one way to look at it. The socle, $S$, is simple as a  unitless ring and as an ideal. Hence if $I$ is an ideal, then either $I = S$ or $I \cap S = \left\{0\right\}$. But the latter implies $R$ is a product of $S$ with another ring (as $S$ is a maximal ideal), which is impossible, since $S$ has no multiplicative identity.

Comment: @DavidHandelman I have three issues. (1) Why $S$ is a simple as an ideal of $R$? (2) Why $S^2=0$ leads to $S=0$ (to conclude that $R$ is prime)? and (3) How does the "countably infinite dimension" of $V$  have to do with the solution? I appreciate, in advance, your reply!

Comment: First, you should check that $S^2 = S$ (because of the proliferation of idempotents), and in fact $S$ is the only two-sided ideal of $E$ (this is just a matrix computation). The dimension of $V$ has to be infinite, or else $E = S$; and if it is uncountable dimensional, then $S$ is merely the minimal proper two-sided ideal of $E$---the construction still works, but $E$ is more complicated.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Thank you very much for your comments. I realized that the right socle of $E$ is the set of those $f$ with finite rank, and that $S^2=S$. Also, by "countably" infinite dimension, I have realized that  $S$ is both the unique minimal and the unique maximal ideal of $E$, so the only ideal thereof. But, I am not persuaded yet why $S$ is a minimal ideal of "$R$". Also, please illuminate more why the right socles of $E$ and $R$ are the same. Thank you again very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57250/discussion-between-karparvar-and-david-handelman).

Comment: @karparvar Since $E$ is von Neumann regular, any ideal of $S$ is an ideal of $E$. An ideal of $R$ would be an ideal of $S$ as well. That's why $S$ is a minimal ideal in $R$.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Why not contribute it as a solution to the question rather than a comment?