# A prime ring which is or is not clean

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

A ring is called clean if each element of which is a sum of a unit and an idempotent. Recently, I asked a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267367/a-boolean-quotient-ring-of-a-prime-ring) about a prime ring $R$ in which $R/Soc(R_R)$ is Boolean  where the right socle $Soc(R_R)$ is non-evident.

My question is whether the ring $R$ in the comment by David Handelman a clean ring?

It is well-known that the ring $E$ in the comment is clean. So, if any element of $R$ which is a unit in $E$ is also a unit in $R$, then $R$ would be  clean too.

Thanks for any suggestion and/or answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if any element of $R$ which is a unit in $E$ is also a unit in $R$, then $R$ would be  clean too.

Well, that is easy to prove, right? Let $1+x\in R$ be a unit in $E$ ($x\in S$ of course.)  Then there exists $y\in E$ such that $(1+x)y=1$. Then $y=1-xy\in R$ since $xy\in S$.

Comment: When $1+x$ is a unit in $E$, why $x\in S$ (the socle $S$ of $E$)? And when $xy\in S$ why $1-xy\in R$?

Comment: @karparvar The subring generated by $1$ and $S$, which we call $R$, is exactly $S\cup \{1+x|x\in S\}$.  (We're in characteristic $2$, remember.)   Obviously none of the units are in $S$, so they can only be in the other half.  You could describe this ring also as the Dorroh extension of $S$ by $F_2$.   $1-xy$ also lies in that half since $xy\in E$.

Comment: Sorry, that last phrase should read "since $xy\in S$."